# MSVS2017 error "expression did not evaluate to a constant" when compile constexpr with lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, if-constexpr

I am using MSVS c++17 and the code below can`t be compiled:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;
 
template <size_t Size, class Pred, size_t idx=0, size_t... pass>
constexpr auto makeIndices(const Pred &pred)
{
    if constexpr(idx >= Size)
    {
        return index_sequence<pass...>();
    }
    else if constexpr(pred(integral_constant<size_t, idx>()))  //<-- HERE!!!!
    {
        return makeIndices<Size, Pred, idx+1, pass..., idx>(pred);
    }
    else
    {
        return makeIndices<Size, Pred, idx+1, pass...>(pred);
    }
}

template <class Tuple, size_t... I>
constexpr auto extract(Tuple&&v, index_sequence<I...> = index_sequence<I...>())
{
    return tuple<tuple_element_t<I, decay_t<Tuple>>...>(get<I>(forward<Tuple>(v))...);
}

template <class Tuple, class Pred>
constexpr auto extract(Tuple&&v, const Pred &pred)
{
    return extract(std::forward<Tuple>(v), makeIndices<tuple_size_v<decay_t<Tuple>>>(pred));
}

template <class Target, class Tuple>
constexpr auto del(Tuple &&v)
{
    return extract(std::forward<Tuple>(v), [](auto idx)
    {
        return !is_same_v<Target, tuple_element_t<idx(), decay_t<Tuple>>>;
    });
}

void MyFunc()
{
    auto src = make_tuple("one", 1, "two", 2, "three", 3, "fourty", 40);
    del<int>(src);
}
```

In the function "makeIndices" I marked place where error appears. Its looks like:

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>
> note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
>
> note: see usage of 'pred'
>
> note: see reference to function template
> instantiation 'auto makeIndices<8,Pred,0,>(const Pred &)' being
> compiled  ...

The code above compiled and worked fine with GCC ([Link](https://godbolt.org/g/LFcfre)).

But how it could be fixed for MSVS?

Comment: "The code above compiled and worked fine with GCC." -- Really? Which version and command-line options? Even after adding the missing `#include` directives and `-std=c++17`, trying this with GCC 8.1, I just get a compiler error.

Comment: `pred` is not a `constexpr` so it can't be called at compile time. Change the lambda in `del()` into a separate `constexpr` function instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau C++17 makes lambdas' `operator()` implicitly `constexpr` if they meet the requirements. According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-constexpr), MSVC has implemented that.

Comment: @hvd: The lambda's `operator()` may be `constexpr`, but `pred` itself is not.

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, because it's a reference parameter where no initialiser is visible, so it cannot be used as a constant expression in the function body. Good point.

Comment: @hvd yes it works fine with GCC 8.1 and -std=c++17. But that is not all code - it is minimal error repro example.

Comment: @guys, so as I understand even if I make this lambda as separate constepr function - I can`t it use as pred parameter? Or in another way I dont get how to change code.

Comment: @AeroSun [This is what happens with your code with GCC 8.1.](https://godbolt.org/g/RRFHHp) If you've omitted code that's required to make it compile, edit your question and add it in.

Comment: @hvd, I update the code and add link to compilation result. Look - it work fine with GCC, but with MSVS appears compilation error

Comment: @AeroSun Right, but with the code you originally posted, it most definitely was *supposed* to give a compilation error. That makes it hard to see exactly what the real problem is, and impossible to test if a particular workaround actually works. Thanks for editing, close vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, MSVC is right to reject this. `pred` is a reference, and inside the function body, it is unknown what object `pred` refers to. Therefore, `pred(...)` is not allowed in constant expressions, even if it wouldn't actually use `pred` at all.

What you can do though, is pass `pred` by value (change `const Pred &pred` to `Pred pred`). Then, `pred` will assuredly refer to a valid object, and that is enough to get MSVC to accept the call.